# finding error while adding firebase ads dependencies in kivy app

Tags: android, python-3.x, java-8, kivy, ads

```
#kivmob app used to manage task in android
from kivy.app import App
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from plyer import notification
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import time
class Toy(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Toy,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store=JsonStore('store.json')
        try:
            self.txt.text=self.store.get('Noted')['note_text']
        except KeyError:
            pass
    def save_notes(self):
        self.store.put('Noted',note_text=self.txt.text)
    def notifications(self):
        while True:
            notification.notify(title='Task Left!!',message=self.txt.text)
            time.sleep(60*60)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            self.ads = KivMob('ca-app-pub-8942943599421136~3157074434')
            self.ads.new_banner('ca-app-pub-8942943599421136/6190555593', top_pos=True)
            self.ads.request_banner()
            self.ads.show_banner()
        except Exception as error:
            pass
            
        return Toy()

MainApp().run()
```

finding error in loading ads in kivy app.Could not connect google firebase ads services in kivy app when using latest version it is showing error and not displaying ads while using previous earlier versions does not show any error but even does not display ads but implementing latest firebase 20.5.0 show error in sdk tools or java tools version.

## Error:

```
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 32.0.0
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:   ---> > Task :mergeExtDexDebug
[DEBUG]:   ompilAGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): android.view.MenuItem androidx.core.internal.view.SupportMenuItem.setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
[DEBUG]:   ompil
[DEBUG]:    > Task :mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Execution failed for task ':mergeExtDexDebug'.
[DEBUG]:    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

## buildozer.spec

```
[app]
# (str) Title of your application
title = Task Handler

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,git+https://github.com/kivy/plyer.git,android,pyjnius,kivmob

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 30

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class instead of PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
android.gradle_dependencies ='com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.5.0'


# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
android.meta_data =com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-8942943599421136~3157074434

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

## Main Error Before packing it into app:

```
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] __init__ called.
[WARNING] [KivMob      ] Ads will not be shown.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] new_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] request_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] show_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.0.3'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'AMD'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.40.0, 5.11.0-46-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: xclip
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event8
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event8>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event8".
```

## Android Debug Log:

```
01-15 15:31:08.279   789  1398 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
01-15 15:31:08.279   789  1398 I python  : AND: Ran string
01-15 15:31:08.279   789  1398 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
01-15 15:31:08.449   789  1398 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
01-15 15:31:08.449   789  1398 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
01-15 15:31:08.460   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/com.notifications.finalapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-01-15_0.txt
01-15 15:31:08.460   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
01-15 15:31:08.461   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/com.notifications.finalapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
01-15 15:31:08.461   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.9 (default, Jan 15 2022, 02:24:31) 
01-15 15:31:08.461   789  1398 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
01-15 15:31:08.461   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
01-15 15:31:09.430   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
01-15 15:31:09.710   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
01-15 15:31:09.745   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
01-15 15:31:10.829   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] __init__ called.
01-15 15:31:10.829   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] Android platform detected.
01-15 15:31:10.837   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] new_banner() called.
01-15 15:31:10.838   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] request_banner() called.
01-15 15:31:10.839   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] show_banner() called.
01-15 15:31:10.863   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
01-15 15:31:10.887   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
01-15 15:31:10.888   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
01-15 15:31:10.888   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r26p0-01eac0.cbce5be1727b5af0b86be8650f76a07f'>
01-15 15:31:10.888   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
01-15 15:31:10.888   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G72 MP3'>
01-15 15:31:10.888   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
01-15 15:31:10.889   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
01-15 15:31:10.889   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
01-15 15:31:10.938   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
01-15 15:31:10.939   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
01-15 15:31:11.045   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
01-15 15:31:11.048   789  1398 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
01-15 15:31:11.048   789  1398 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
After running app ads not shown part in above error changes to Android platform detected

Comment: the kivmob doc says use `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'` instead of `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.5.0'`

Comment: @Hussan F.Alkdary I have also used 10.2.0 but ads not showing

Comment: can you share the error you got while using `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'` also try to change the `package.domain` from `org.test` to some thing else does not contain test

Comment: @HussamF.Alkdary There is no error but ads are not shown. I have updated the error please kindly help me in this part when I run main.py in pc it shows ads not shown warning but after packaging and running in android this ads not shown part changes to Android platform detected.

Comment: @HussamF.Alkdary kindly please look into this updated main error part.I have also changed package domain to com.notifications

Comment: this windows log right can you show android log where the problem happens

Comment: @HussamF.AlkdarySee I have added android log at last. no error is showing but ads are not shown can you fix this?See in ubuntu log it is showing ads not shown but in android log it changes to Android platform detected but still no ads are shown

Comment: try to follow the ReadME file and change you spec file as described there

Comment: @Hussam F.Alkdary could we point me out particular changes in my buildozer.spec file as I have tried according to readme file of kivmob but showing error but when I comment out minapi,sdk and ndk version no error is shown but still ads are not visible.